# Custom UITableViewCell UIButton setTitle not working as planned

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that presents custom UITableViewCells containing a UIButton. The button title is set according to whether or not the song title (associated with that cell) has been added to an array of Strings called trackList. If trackList contains the title, the button title should display as "Remove", else it should display as "Add".

This seems to work fine at first, but as you scroll up or down in the table, the button titles change. For example, if I have 10 items in the table, and none in trackList, I scroll down and all of the buttons display "Add" as expected. If I then scroll back to the top, tap on the "Add" button in the first cell, the button title changes to "Remove" and the first cell's title is added to trackList, as expected. But if I then scroll down, I also find that the 6th cell's button title has been changed to "Remove"?! Likewise, if I then tap the 2nd cell's button, both the 2nd and 7th cell's button's change. Or if I tap the 8th cell's button, both the 8th and the 3rd cell's button's change. This is not reflected in the trackList array (if I perform all three of the above button taps, trackList only contains the title of 1st, 2nd, and 8th cells).

I'm sure there is a better way to structure this, but with my current noob level of swift programming experience, This was the first way that came to mind when trying to decouple an array of available tracks, with an array that I use as a playlist elsewhere. I'd be very grateful for any guidance in either working out why the buttons are acting this way (i.e. also changing the title of the button at cellIndex +- 5), or perhaps suggest an alternate structure for dealing with this. Here's the custom cell code...

```
class PurchasedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var isAdded: Bool = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()   
}
@IBOutlet weak var SongTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var SongAddOrRemoveButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func addOrRemoveSong(_ sender: Any) {
    var tempIsAdded = false
    for check in trackList {
        if (check == purchasedSongTitleLabel.text!){
            tempIsAdded = true
        }
    }
    isAdded = tempIsAdded
    if isAdded {
        purchasedSongAddOrRemoveButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        trackList.remove(at: trackList.index(of: purchasedSongTitleLabel.text!)!)
    } else {
        purchasedSongAddOrRemoveButton.setTitle("Remove", for: .normal)
        trackList.append(purchasedSongTitleLabel.text!)
    }
    self.superview?.reloadInputViews()
    }
}
```

... and for the cells in the table view...

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 20
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellInt = indexPath.row
        if (cellInt < purchasedBeats.count){
            var cell = PurchasedTableViewCell()
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Purchased", for: indexPath) as! PurchasedTableViewCell
            cell.purchasedSongTitleLabel.text = purchasedBeats[cellInt]
            for check in trackList {
                if (check == purchasedBeats[cellInt]){
                    cell.isAdded = true
                }
            }
            if cell.isAdded {
                cell.purchasedSongAddOrRemoveButton.setTitle("Remove", for: .normal) 
            } else {
                cell.purchasedSongAddOrRemoveButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)  
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cells are reused. You are changing the title in the view but not in the model. You need to mirror the `isAdded` variable in the model.

Comment: Oh, so `cell.isAdded` is not enough? I actually have to use `indexPath.row` to query my model?

Comment: @vadian , you are a legend! I made `purchasedBeats` into an array of tuples instead `[String, Bool]`. Prolly not the most elegant solution, but it does the trick :) Thank a million

Comment: Actually I meant to make the type in purchasedBeats as class `class Beat { var name : String; var isAdded: Bool }` and pass the instance in `cellForRowAt` to the custom cell class. Then you can change the property directly in the instance and you can omit most of the custom code in the custom cell.